# Pull post from a specific month

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic, hyperlink

I am trying to pull posts from a specific month that has been clicked on, on a different page.....  So to make it a little more clear.

I have a page which displays each month that a post has been made in, I then have a second page that page one is linked to. The second page is for showing the posts from the month that has been selected in the previous page.

below is the code to display the months and the link I created for the user to click on

```
$months = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(MONTHNAME(date)) as post_month
                       FROM article
                       LIMIT 12");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($months)){
    echo "<a href=\"montharticles.php?id=" . $row['0'] . "\">" . $row['0'] . "</a><br/>";
}
```

below is the code for the second page

```
$article = mysql_query("SELECT article_id, content, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b %y') 
                       FROM article
                       WHERE article_id = $_GET[id]");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($article)){
    echo $row . "</br>";
}
```

my issue is that when page two is opened I get an error message.

I have removed $_GET[id] and replaced it with a number, doing this just displays "array"
I have also tried $_GET[month] but no luck

I realise that there is a problem with the $_GET[] part of the statement and that if a month is clicked I need to make whats in the address bar = to whats in the $_GET command, but I cant work out how to do it.

Comment: Oh no, [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: The error message is Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. I have realised why that didnt show anything now, but I still cant display all results from a specific month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$row` is an array that includes an entire row of the result set.

To access a particular column in the row, you need to do something like this:

```
echo $row['article_id'];
```

You'll probably want to use an alias for the date column like this:

```
SELECT article_id, content, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b %y') AS date_column
```

So you can do this:

```
echo $row['date_column'];
```

Instead of this:

```
echo $row["DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b %y')"];
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am now trying to use $_GET['month'] to access the month which the user has clicked on, but without success. I have tried    $article = mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM article
                            WHERE monthname(date) = $_GET['month']"); as well as several other variations. I assumed I was simply pulling id= January from the address bar...this is obviously incorrect what is the right answer?

Comment: @tony09uk, that is a different question. Please vote on the answers, and accept one if it applies. You need to remove the single quotes around the key name of an array variable in order to have it expand within a double quoted string or put `{}` around the array variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get "array" is because `$row` is an array. As Ami said you need to access one of the values in the array.

On your first page your ref goes to `montharticles.php?id=ID`, you have to make sure that the id attribute is filled by looking at the address bar and then on the second page try to echo it out (`echo $_GET['id'];`) somewhere.

Comment: Hi again, im still trying to figure this problem out.